# How to change the URL path in Apache?

Tags: apache

I have a url now that is accessed like:

http://s1.name.com/healthApp

I want it to be accessed it like

http://healthApp.name.com

How do I set this up in Apache (Cent OS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to setup:

- A DNS entry pointing the DNS entry healthApp.name.com to your webserver
- A VirtualHost entry on the server to handle this new host name
- Set the DocumentRoot of the new vHost to the healthApp directory
- Check any configuration of your web application so it knows it's running from the new location